# is there any way to usestate respond immediately?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I was wanting to get value from the my server of the node with the usestate, but it returns the empty array value first and then pops up the value of my axios

has any way of the value of the axios appears first than that of the empty array ?

my code:

```html
const [valTop, valTopstate] = useState([])

    async function MusicTop() {
        axios("http://localhost:3001/")
        .then(res=>{
            valTopstate(res.data.tracks.data)
        })
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        MusicTop()

    }, [valTop])
```

Comment: No, because the component renders with the initial state first, and that Axios request is an async process so will take time to appear. You may want your component to have a message or a spinner to indicate that data is being fetched before the array is mapped. `MusicTop` should also be in a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array so it gets called after the first render. And maybe call it `musicTop`. Functions and classes have different notation (Pascal-case for classes, camel-case for functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine but UseEffect is executed only after the component is rendered, so you can apply a logic that is the array is empty then show the loader and if not show the array values, and if this is your child component what you can do is that when this child component is going to be executed then you can first fetch the required array value by calling a function in the parent component and pass the values as props in the child component.